# Remove duplicates in Table Join with Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to be able to select distinct "phone" regardless if the phone comes from work or home. All phones need to be unique.

This query produces duplicates when the same phone is found in work and home in different rows.

```
SELECT CASE WorkPhone
        WHEN '' THEN 
            HomePhone
        ELSE 
            WorkPhone
        END AS Phone
       ,MAX(LastName)
       ,MAX(FirstName)
FROM   TableA
WHERE  (statusid = Inactive)
        AND 
            (modifieddate > '11/11/2011')       
        AND 
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT Phone FROM TableB WHERE Phone = WorkPhone OR Phone = HomePhone)      
        AND 
            NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT AreaCode + PhoneNumber FROM TableC 
            WHERE   
                (AreaCode = LEFT(WorkPhone,3) AND PhoneNumber = Substring(WorkPhone, 4, 7)
                )
                OR
                (AreaCode = LEFT(HomePhone,3) AND PhoneNumber = Substring(HomePhone, 4, 7))                             
                )

GROUP BY WorkPhone, HomePhone
```

Comment: What happens if they have two different work numbers, or different work and home? Do you have to designate if the number is a work number or a home number? I think more detail on the requirements are needed.

Comment: We go for Work number first and only choose home if work is missing.

Comment: You need (1) distinct work phones and home phones (a phone number _can be_ work phone `AND` home phone) for every FirstName and LastName or you need (2) distinct work & home phones (a phone number _is_ work phone `OR` home phone) for every FirstName and LastName or you need (3) distinct work & home phones ?

Answer (score 2):

You should group by:

```
CASE WorkPhone
        WHEN '' THEN 
            HomePhone
        ELSE 
            WorkPhone
        END
```

instead of grouping by `WorkPhone, HomePhone`

Comment: Can't you group by the the aliased column (`phone`)?  In any case, this is what I identify as the issue as well.

Comment: @X-Zero - You can't group by the alias unless you use a derived table